# Are votes still locked if a rollback is made by the OP?

Tags: support, voting, locked-votes

[Votes on posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked) are locked after the grace period.

What if a user makes an edit to a post but the OP rollbacked the edit to their original revision, will the votes cast still be locked?

Theoretically, the post wasn't changed since the OP rollbacked it to their original version.

Comment: The new version should have the edit summary "[Removed during grace period]", so votes should be unlocked.

Comment: All votes should be unlocked after every edit, even if that edit is a roll back.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks but doesn't that defeat the purpose of having the vote lock in the first place?

Comment: Not really.  If the edit changes the post then your vote might change as well.  If the post is edited to be clear and useful after you down voted it wouldn't you want to remove the down vote?  Conversely, if an edit made the post go from good to bad and you down vote afterwards, wouldn't you want to remove that if the edit was rolled back and the post is no longer bad?

Comment: @NathanOliver That makes sense too, thanks!